# MongoDB - Users not restored using command mongorestore

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm testing some basic backup and restore operations in a single MongoDB instance.

All tests worked fine except for restoring users.

I first created a backup of a test database (*db_test*) using the following command:

```
$ mongodump -u adm_dump --authenticationDatabase admin -d db_test --dumpDbUsersAndRoles -o /opt/backup/mongodump_db_test
```

*adm_dump* is a user I created with "restore" and "backup" roles.

2 users are present in *db_test* database with "readWrite" and "read" roles respectively. So I was expecting these both users to be restored.

Then I restored the database into database *db_test_2* (not existing):

```
$ mongorestore -u adm_dump --authenticationDatabase admin -d db_test_2 --restoreDbUsersAndRoles /opt/backup/mongodump_db_test/db_test
```

The new database *db_test_2* is successfully created (all collections are restored) but users are not restored in *db_test2*.

Below the log tail:

```
...
2016-06-29T18:28:26.429+0200    restoring users from /opt/backup/mongodump_db_test/db_test/$admin.system.users.bson
2016-06-29T18:28:26.464+0200    roles file '/opt/backup/mongodump_db_test/db_test/$admin.system.roles.bson' is empty; skipping roles restoration
2016-06-29T18:28:26.464+0200    restoring roles from /opt/backup/mongodump_db_test/db_test/$admin.system.roles.bson
2016-06-29T18:28:26.468+0200    done
```

I also granted the "userAdmin" role to *adm_dump* and did operations several times with no success. Should I give another specific role to *adm_dump* user ?

I read the doc and googled on dumpDbUsersAndRoles / restoreDbUsersAndRoles options but found nothing relevant.

What did I miss to restore users from a dump backup ?

MongoDB version 3.2.1 on CentOS 6.6

Comment: The users are actually stored in the *admin* database; when you mongorestore the db_test data into a new db_test_2 database, it might be going wrong by recreating the users in the admin database with their privileges on db_test, instead of db_test_2 as you wished. If you log in at the console and execute `user admin;` then `db.system.users.find();`, that will help show you what user accounts do exist.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else is trying to do this...

1. Don't specify a db or a collection in mongo dump.
2. Log in as a user that has admin privileges (maybe `adm_dump` has those privileges?)
3. Don't use `--dumpDbUsersAndRoles`, this only applies when you specify a db.  See the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-dumpdbusersandroles).

Example:

```
$ mongodump -u adm_dump --authenticationDatabase admin --dumpDbUsersAndRoles -o /opt/backup/mongodump_db_test
```

Comment: Thanks @ali Abbas Jaffri